# java swing label with html tag - white spaces disappearing

Tags: java, html, swing, jlabel

I am trying to color one character in the string, but when i do so most of the whitespaces dissapear. Why does that happen and is there any solution?

```
map[9]  =       "#                                     #        ####     #";
map[10] =       "#                                     #        #        #";
map[11] = "<html>#                                     #        #<font color=YELLOW>.</font>       #</hmtl>";
map[12] =       "#   ###################################        #        #";
map[13] =       "#   #                                 #        ####     #";
```

I am assigning the strings to the array and later set each string to its own JLabel

I already tried putting in unicode whitespace characters (normal whitespace *\u0020* and no-break whitespace *\u00A0*):
The no-break whitespace worked but i later have to check if there is a whitespace at the playerposition and i did'nt get that to work properly with *\u00A0*.

also, when i use the html tag for the string the (text or JLabel - i don't know which of both) is offset to the bottom a bit. How can I get it to stay in the same position as without the html tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spaces disappear, because HTML is whitespace-agnostic. This means that the structure and layout of the document does not depend on whether there are spaces, tabs and newlines, and how many they are.

This is by specification and is required for all HTML parsers, including "pseudo HTML" usages like in JLabel (which supports only a minimal subset of HTML for basic formatting).

Possible solutions:

- try using `&nbsp;` instead of the Unicode. This may lead to the same side effects though
- try surrounding each space in its own element, for example a `<span>`, `<b>` or similar. This may work, but would make it very cumbersome. Also, not sure if JLabel can handle spans.

Other than that, if you are trying to achieve some kind of a progress indicator or a "seek line", maybe there are better solutions than a colored JLabel, for example a JProgressBar...

Comment: Ok thank, you the &nbsp did the Job. And thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @Tikka, don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.